# Wie heißt ein "med pod" auf deutsch?

Tags: single-word-request

Im Science-Fiction-Film *[Prometheus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_%E2%80%93_Dunkle_Zeichen)* werden medizinische Operationen in einem sogenannten "[MedPod](http://weyland.wikia.com/wiki/MedPod)" vorgenommen:

[image]

In der Regel dienen diese Geräte nicht nur einem einzelnen Zweck, wie die [Eiserne Lunge](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiserne_Lunge) oder der [Inkubator](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkubator_(Medizin)), sondern sind Multifunktions- oder gar "Allheilgeräte", die manchmal, wie im Film *Das Fünfte Element*, den ursprünglichen Zustand eines Körpers [allein aus seiner DNA wiederherstellen können](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9OBbsLYGOE).

Wie heißt (bzw. hieße) so etwas auf deutsch?

---

Die "Med-Bays" im Film *[Elysium](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_(2013))* werden im Internet als "medizinische Behandlungsgeräte" übersetzt. In der Synchronfassung des Films heißen sie "Medi-Bank".

Im Roman *Das Kosmotop* von Andreas Brandhorst gibt es den "Genesungstank", das ist ein "Behälter, der einen Patienten aufnimmt und seine Verletzungen heilt".

---

Möglich wäre eine Benennung nach:

- dem Fachgebiet: **Medizin** (wie in Medizintechnik)
- dem Ausgangszustand: **krank** (wie in Krankenwagen)
- dem Vorgang:

  - **behandeln** (wie in Behandlungsliege)
  - **heilen** (wie in Heilanstalt)
- dem Zielzustand: **gesund** (wie in Gesundbrunnen)
- der Form:

  - **Kapsel**
  - **Kammer**
  - **Liege**
  - **Behälter**
- der verwendeten (fiktionalen) Technologie:

  - **re-atomisieren** (im Film Elysium)
- usw.

---

Hier eine *Druck**kammer***, die vielleicht die Bezeichnung *Medi-Kammer* oder *Heilkammer* nahelegt. Zwar sind Druckkammern häufig eher [busgroß](https://www.google.de/search?q=druckkammer&tbm=isch) und nehmen mehrere Personen gleichzeitig auf, offenbar gibt es sie aber auch für [einzelne Personen](http://www.banja-vrucica.com/de/gesundheit/druckkammer/) und in der Größe eines MedPod:

[image]

Comment: Irgendwas mit _Kapsel_?

Comment: Im Buch Alien - In den Schatten von Tim Lebbon wird es nicht übersetzt und einfach *Med-Pod* genannt. [siehe Link](https://books.google.at/books?id=1xybAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT210&lpg=PT210&dq=in+den+medpod+steigen&source=bl&ots=TtM1UgFv64&sig=GMVPkvQlqVkcBj4WBssyqOHh3qI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo6a_g18PPAhUqJcAKHYZjC24Q6AEIHzAA#v=snippet&q=med%20pod&f=false)

Comment: @Ingmar Das macht Sinn, wenn man bedenkt, dass ein "escape pod" auf deutsch "Rettungskapsel" heißt, andererseits heißt eine "Raumkapsel" auf englisch "space capsule": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_capsule

Comment: @jera Danke, ja, das hatte ich mir beinahe schon gedacht. Andererseits spielt dieses Buch in einer Welt, die sich die Leser trotz der Übersetzung wahrscheinlich als englischsprachig vorstellen (schon der Titel heißt ja "Alien", nicht "Außerirdische", und wer es liest, weiß ja um den amerikanischen Film mit seinen amerikanischen Helden). Ich stelle mir vor, dass so ein Gerät vielleicht doch einen deutschen Namen bekäme, wenn es in allen deutschen Krankenhäusern stehen würde.

Comment: Achso, du meinst also nur ein Gerät dieser Art? Nicht exakt dieses Teil im Prometheus Film? Dann würde ich vielleicht sowas wie Medi-Kapsel vorschlagen - das hab ich auch schon in einem Buch gelesen. ......Alternativ könntest du darüber nachdenken, Med Pod im Sinne der allgemeinen Verenglischung zu übernehmen, weil es ja mega hip und cool klingt.

Comment: Kapsel, Schrein, Zentrum, Röhre, Kammer, Station, Kokon, fallen mir da auf Anhieb ein. Leider natürlich auch "Sarg"...

Comment: Die Frage ist wohl eher gibt es überhaupt schon ein offiziells Wort dafür?

Comment: @Anetair: Bei solchen Themen geht es vermutlich weniger um *offizielle* Begriffe als um (für Muttersprachler) *plausible* Begriffe.

Comment: @what: Warum wird eigentlich überhaupt ein Begriff für dieses Gerät gesucht?

Comment: @äüö Um auf deutsch darüber reden und schreiben zu können.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In der Medizin gibt es zwei Begriffe für den Vorgang der Heilung, die *restitutio* und die *reparatio*. Die *[restitutio ad intregrum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restitutio_ad_integrum)*, das heißt die "Wiederherstellung der Unversehrtheit", bezeichnet die Abheilung einer Erkrankung ohne bleibende Schäden, bei der der ursprüngliche Funktionszustand vollständig wiederhergestellt wird. Demgebenüber wird bei der *[reparatio](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defektheilung)* oder "Defektheilung" der Gewebeschaden durch Narbengewebe ersetzt und es bleiben Funktionsbeeinträchtigungen zurück.

Da das fiktionale Gerät eine Wiederherstellung der Unversehrtheit oder gar eine [Rejuvenation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verj%C3%BCngung_(Altern)) bewirken soll, würde es von den medizintechnischen Herstellern möglicherweise unter Verwendung der schon bestehenden und in der Fachwelt gebräuchlichen Begriffe als

## Restitutor

bezeichnet werden. Dieser Begriff hat den Vorteil, dass er für Mediziner unmittelbar verständlich ist, außerdem kurz und prägnant und durch keinerlei verwirrende Vorbedeutungen belegt. Allein als Bezeichung für römische Kaiser ist er auf [römischen Münzen](https://www.google.de/search?q=restitutor&tbm=isch) erhalten, aber außerhalb der Geschichtswissenschaft und Numismatik ist diese Verwendung sicher weitgehend unbekannt.

Da die medizinischen Laien sich unter Restitution aber nichts vorstellen können, werden sie das Gerät umgangssprachlich wahrscheinlich einen

## Heiler

nennen. Dieses Wort hat heute schon keinen Referenten mehr, da es den Beruf des Heilers – wenn man mal vom Geistheiler absieht – seit einigen Hundert Jahren nicht mehr gibt. Gleichwohl ist das Wort weiterhin bekannt und verbreitet und seine Bedeutung ist jedem Sprecher des Deutschen zumindest über verwandte Wörter wie "heilen" jedem geläufig.

Zudem neigt die Umgangsprache zu substantivierten Verben als Bezeichnung für Geräte, wie die zahlreichen Bildungen belegen: Flieger (Flugzeug), Schreiber (Kugelschreiber, allg. Schreibstift), Brüter (Brutreaktor), Roller (Tretroller, Motorroller), Kocher u.v.m.

Answer (score 6):

Ich würde **Medi-Kapsel** vorschlagen - das hab ich im Buch *[Die Judasrose](https://books.google.at/books?id=S5G3DAAAQBAJ&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* von Suzette Haden Elgin gefunden.

Alternativ könntest du darüber nachdenken, Med Pod im Sinne der allgemeinen Verenglischung zu übernehmen, weil es ja mega hip und cool klingt.

---

Im Buch *Alien - In den Schatten* von Tim Lebbon wird die Bezeichnung übrigens nicht übersetzt und einfach Med-Pod genannt. Siehe [Google Books](https://books.google.at/books?hl=de&id=1xybAwAAQBAJ&dq=tim%20lebbon%20alien&q=med%20pod#v=snippet&q=med%20pod&f=false)

Comment: Gute Idee. "Kapsel" hat allerdings den Nachteil, dass es im medizinischen Zusammenhang bereits eine Arzneiform bezeichnet (s. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapsel_(Medikament)), so dass jemand, der das Wort ohne Kontext hört, wohl immer an eine "Pille" denken wird.

Comment: @what Ja, da bin ich bei dir. Ich denke allerdings, dass es durch den Zusammenhang leicht herauszufinden wäre (z.B. eine Person wird in die Medi-Kapsel gelegt, eine Person wird in der Medi-Kapsel behandelt, die Medi-Kapsel wird von Putzkräften gereinigt und desinfiziert).

Comment: Medpod oder Med-Pod, ein Leerzeichen trennt im Deutschem Wörter und verbindet sie nicht.

Comment: Was mir an den Bezeichnungen mit "Medi-" gut gefällt, ist, dass ihre medizinische Heilfunktion unmittelbar aus dem Namen ersichtlich ist. Ich frage mich allerdings, ob man sich die Medi-Kapsel nicht doch besser als **Medi-Kammer** vorstellt, so wie die Druckkammer, die es zwar als Mehrpersonenkammer gibt, aber auch als MedPod-großes Gerät: http://www.banja-vrucica.com/de/gesundheit/druckkammer/

Answer (score 6):

Da es den Inkubator gibt, würde es vielleicht **Regenerator** heißen. Das klingt nach deutschem Sprachgefühl auch schön medizinisch, wäre aber trotzdem wahrscheinlich fürs Volk als Begriff akzeptabel. Ein ganz einfaches deutsches Wort, etwa wie Heilkapsel oder ähnliches, wäre vielleicht im Jahre 1916 gut angekommen, aber nicht mehr 100 Jahre später...

Comment: Den Regenerator finde ich bisher fast am besten. Allerdings denke ich bei Regeneration eher an Erholung nach dem Sport, so dass es sein könnte, dass die Leser das Gerät allein dem Namen nach nicht als Heilgerät sondern als eine Art vollautomatischer Massageliege ansehen. Die Wiederherstellung der Gesundheit heißt in der Medizin nicht Regeneration sondern *restitutio ad integrum*, insofern könnte man das Gerät nach dem Muster des Regenerators vielleicht **Restitutor** nennen.

Comment: @what: Stimmt, das ist dann noch logischer. Mir fehlt hier ein bisschen das medizinische Wissen, um's genau auf den Punkt zu bringen, aber das Prinzip ist klar und der Weg zum Zielwort sollte nun geebnet sein. :-) *Restitutor* kann ich mir auch gut im nächsten Duden vorstellen.

Comment: ... wobei die Leute sich noch eher etwas unter regenerieren vorstellen können als unter restitutieren...

Comment: Definitiv. Müsste man jetzt mal schauen, wie das Wort Regeneration von der Bildungssprache in die Umgangssprache gelangt ist. So könnte man sich das dann vielleicht auch für den Restitutor vorstellen ...

Comment: Als was es die Leute dem Namen nach ansehen, hängt auch immer viel mit Assoziationen zusammen, die automatisch gedanklich versucht werden, da der Mensch immer sofort nach Ähnlichkeiten zu anderen Begriffen sucht. Ich für meinen Teil denke beim *Regenerieren* aber nicht an Massagestudios, sondern mehr in Richtung "Wiederaufbau".

Comment: ... jedoch irgendwie gewichtet auf Erholung, da gebe ich dir recht.

Answer (score 4):

Ich finde

> Med-Kokon

oder

> Behandlungskokon

oder

> Heilkokon

sehr brauchbar, vor allem wegen der runden Formen und weil die Patienten (hoffentlich) in einem anderen, besseren Zustand wieder rauskommen als sie reingegangen sind - Analog zum Insekt.

Answer (score 3):

1. Es ist eine Liege
2. Sie ist voll-automatisch
3. Sie behandelt den Liegenden

Vollautomatische Behandlungsliege

Comment: I glaub nicht, denn das gibt's schon, und es ist etwas anderes: https://www.google.de/search?q=%22vollautomatische+behandlungsliege%22&tbm=isch

Comment: Brat-Rost, Eisen-Rost ? Coach = Kutsche oder Coach = Bus? Das wäre nicht das 1. Wort mit mehreren anwendungen.

Comment: Ich würde das nicht Liege nennen. Liegen haben gewöhnlich keine gläserne Dächer und Seitenwände

Comment: Man sollte mMn aber auch beachten, dass sich Neuerungen in der Sprache gewöhnlich auf Basis existierender Begriffe bilden. Heute nennt man das, worauf Patienten während der Behandlung liegen, meist "Liege", vielleicht noch (Operations-)"Tisch". Also dürfte sich für diese fiktive Weiterentwicklung mit einiger Wahrscheinlichkeit ein Begriff auf dieser Basis einbürgern. Das hängt natürlich davon ab, ob man einen "realistisch" klingenden Begriff will, oder einen "typisch SF" klingenden, konstruierten. Mein Favorit ist aktuell "Medi-Liege"; das wäre auch einfach genug für die Hektik im Notfall.

Answer (score 3):

Ich glaube, dass man *Pod* hier auch mit *Box* übersetzen könnte, was zum einen ja allgemein einen Behälter bezeichnet, zum anderen auch einen abgegrenzten Raum (z.B. für Pferde oder Rennautos; letztere werden dort sogar "behandelt" ;-)). Der Zweck des Geräts wird mit "heilen" oder "medizinisch" gut beschrieben. Foglich schlage ich vor

- **Heilbox** oder
- **Medi-Box**

Comment: Medi-Box. So ein Produkt mit diesem Name ist schon vorhanden :) https://www.bbraun.de/de/products/b/medibox.html

Comment: @AdInfinitum [Das trifft auf den zu übersetzenden Namen auch zu](http://dayamed.com/).

Comment: Ich denke, alle Namen, die mit *Med* beginnen, sind schon zuminst einmal benutzt. +1 für Heilbox übrigens.

Comment: Hmm ... Kühlbox.

Answer (score 3):

Ich schicke den **Heilomat** ins Rennen.

Comment: Sehr schön! Funktioniert aber auch nur, wenn man einen humoristischen Beiklang haben möchte ;)

Comment: @ma_il: So wie in Tempomat, Bankomat, ...?

Comment: Ich würde die nicht unbedingt gleichsetzen. "Tempomat" ist ein inzwischen etablierter umgangssprachlicher Begriff, entsprungen aus der gleichnamigen Daimler-Marke. Aber z.B. "Bankomat" wird - zumindest in meinem Umfeld - immer mit explizit humoristischen Unterton als Alternative für "Geldautomat" gebraucht.

Comment: @ma_il: Dann ist Dir bestimmt aufgefallen, dass humoristischer Unterton etwas ist, das man mit der Stimme macht, ergo auch anders machen kann. In Österreich bin ich Bankomat als offizieller Bezeichnung begegnet. Inwiefern Dein Kurzessay über Tempomat ein Argument sein soll entgeht mir völlig. Desweiteren gebe ich Dir einen Automat zum Knabbern.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, wie wär's mit

> MediKlav

(analog zum Autoklav ein geschlossenes Behältnis, in dem etwas behandelt <sup>(hoho)</sup> wird)

Oder

> MediStat

(von Behandlungsstation, evtl. sogar mit schwacher Assoziation zu Stasis-Kapseln, -Kammern o.ä.)

Natürlich gibt's beides schon als Produktnamen für Geräte oder Medikamente :(

Comment: Das Deutsche kennt keine Großbuchstaben im Wortinneren.

Comment: @userunknown Das Englische auch nicht - trotzdem suchen wir eine Übersetzung für _MedPod_.

Comment: @Matthias: Weil das Korrektorat des Autors uns nicht gefragt hat.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde **Kabinenheiler** vorschlagen

Comment: Ich fände Heilkabine besser ;)

Comment: So hab ich zuerst auch gedacht, aber diese Paraphrase auf dem Messersmitter Erzeugnis "Kabinenroller" der 50er Jahren klingte mir "deutscher" ;)

Comment: @Beta Der "Kabinenroller" ist ja ein Roller mit Kabine. Die Kabine beim Kabinenroller ist ein nicht essentieller Luxus, und der Roller fährt auch ohne sie. Entsprechend wäre ein "Kabinenheiler" ein Heiler mit Kabine, das impliziert aber, dass es den auch ohne Kabine gibt, als bloßen "Heiler", und dass er als kabinenloser Heiler genauso funktioniert (nur vielleicht das Blut im Raum rumspritzt). Und tatsächlich kommt im Film *Elysium* keine Kabine vor, insofern wäre dein Vorschlag eigentlich, das Gerät einen **Heiler** zu nennen, der Kabinenheiler wäre eine Variante.

Comment: Den "Heiler" könnte man dann noch als "Sanator" latinisieren.

Answer (score 1):

Mein Vorschlag;

CM (steht für **Corpusmedicus**)

die Bedeutungen von der lateinischen Begriffe

**Corpus** = Körper

**Medicus** = Heiler

Comment: Offenbar ist *photoakustischer* ein dekliniertes deutsches Adjektiv - wieso dann alles in einem Wort? Und wieso überhaupt *photoakustisch*? Wird *Medizintechnologie* heutzutage wirklich mit lateinischen Namen versehen?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Latenische Wörter in der Medizintechnologie zu benutzen ist natürlich keine Pflicht  aber auch nicht verboten. Der Gerät heilt den Körper mit Lichtenergie und deswegen habe ich *photoakustisch* passend gefunden.

Comment: Mit Lichtenergie? Sicher, in der [fraglichen Szene aus *Prometheus*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW4PH2ibdh4) kommt auch ein Laser zum Einsatz, aber was haben denn der Greifer, der den eigentlichen Eingriff durchführt, sowie die Verschlussklammern mit Lichtenergie zu tun? Und auch dann, wieso *akustisch*? Kommen auch Schallwellen zum Einsatz? Bezüglich des Namens wollte ich darauf hinaus, ob es überhaupt Medizintechnologieprodukte gibt, die auf Lateinisch benannt werden (und zwar nicht nur so, dass auf einen bereits vor dem Produkt existierenden Fachbegriff Bezug genommen wird).

Comment: Die Definition von Laser: "Licht-Verstärkung durch stimulierte Emission von Strahlung". d.H Laser ist auch eine umwandelte Art von Licht. Die Defitinition von *photoakustischer Effekt* besagt; "Photoakustischer Effekt beschreibt die Umwandlung von Lichtenergie in akustische Energie (Schall)". Ich weiß es auch nicht ob es ein Medizintechnologieprodukt mit dem lateinischen Name gibt.

Comment: Bitte lies meinen Kommentar nochmal. Ich habe darauf hingewiesen, dass die Behandlung zumindest im angesprochenen Film eben **nicht nur** mittels Lasern stattfand (die eigentliche "Behandlung" hatte in der Tat nichts mit Lasern zu tun; der Laser wurde nur für den Schnitt benutzt). Ebenso hatte ich gefragt, wo in der besagten Szene Schall angewendet wird. "Ich weiß es auch nicht ob es ein Medizintechnologieprodukt mit dem lateinischen Name gibt." - das stärkt jetzt nicht unbedingt die oben angegebene Begründung.

Comment: Ach so. Ich habe den Film nicht geguckt. Die Szene, die Du mir geschickt hast, habe ich jetzt nochmal (diesmal bis zum Ende) geguckt. Ich dachte, dieser Gerät (von der Optik) ist sehr technologisch aber ich bin enttäuscht. Ich bearbeite mein Vorschlag dann :)

Comment: @what: 'Wenn das "photoakustisch" vor sich geht, ist das völlig in Ordnung im Rahmen meiner Frage.' - das tut es ja, wie oben gezeigt, eben *nicht* in jedem Fall. *Photoakustischer ...* ist somit kein passender Begriff, der auf alle Geräte gemäß deiner Definition anwendbar ist.

Comment: @what: "Es könnte ja sein, dass sie in der wirklichen Zukunft photoakustisch funktionieren." - ja, aber es könnte eben auch sein, dass sie *nicht* photoakustisch funktionieren, wodurch *photoakustischer ...* unpassend wäre. Wenn du einen Oberbegriff suchst, sollte er schon für alle deiner Definition entsprechenden Geräte passen, oder? Davon abgesehen ist das Wort *Medizin* vom lateinischen *mederi* abgeleitet, was einfach *heilen* bedeutet. Eine "nicht-medizinische Heilung" ist somit ein Widerspruch in sich.

Comment: @what: Dann gehe ich davon aus, dass beispielsweise "hölzerner, mit Fuchsfell veredelter Behandlungskasten mit 14 Operationsgreifarmen" auch eine valide Antwort wäre, denn deine Frage schließt auch keines der darin genannten spezifischen Merkmale aus.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Natürlich ist sie eine valide Antwort aber du bekommst bestimmt viele Downvotes.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Das sagt dann wohl Einiges über die Beantwortbarkeit deiner Frage aus. Um die Diskussion nicht ins Endlose wachsen zu lassen, bleibt mir als Fazit wohl, dass die (eigentlich sehr interessante) Frage in der aktuellen Form off-topic ist, da du nicht nach einem korrekten/verständlichen Begriff gemäß einer Definition suchst, sondern eigentlich auch nach Vorschlägen für die Definition selbst. Das wäre wohl besser in [Worldbuilding SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) aufgehoben.

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin nicht davon überzeugt, dass Inkubator nicht passt. Laut Wikipedia

> Medizinprodukt, mit dessen Hilfe kontrollierte Außenbedingungen für diverse Brut- und Wachstumsprozesse geschaffen und erhalten werden können

Erst im Anschluss daran wird auf Brutkästen spezialisiert.

Mein Alternativvorschlag ist:

> Regenerationstank

*Regeneration*, wenn es sich um tiefergreifende Reparaturen handelt, *Tank* weil speziell wenn es sich um Aufbau aus Erbmasse handelt, die Baustein in gelöster Form zugeführt werden.

Answer (score 0):

*Ich schicke jetzt auch mal eine eigene Antwort ins Rennen. Unabhängig von der Bewertung dieser meiner eigenen Antwort werde ich die* bounty *am Ende auf jeden Fall einer anderen Antwort verleihen.*

Die meisten medizinischen Geräte heute tragen eine Bezeichnung, die aus ihrer Funktion abgeleitet ist: die Spritze spritzt, der Verband verbindet. Wenn wir uns das Gerät, um das es hier geht, aber als "Allheilgerät" vorstellen, dann werden mit der Erfindung dieses Geräts aber auch alle anderen medizinschen Geräte überflüssig, da deren Funktionen in diesem Gerät vereint sind. Tatsächlich würde, wenn dieses Gerät jede Art von Erkrankung heilen kann, *der Beruf des Arztes verschwinden*. Es gäbe dann nur noch dieses Gerät – und Medizintechniker. Damit würden aber alle Begriffe, die bisher andere Geräte (und medizinische Berufe) kennzeichnen, frei werden. Oder anders gesagt, **dieses Gerät repräsentiert die Gesamtheit der praktischen Medizin**. Deshalb würde es sicher auch eine Bezeichnung bekommen, die diesen Status beschreibt.

Da es nur noch ein einziges medizinisches Gerät und kein medizinisches Personal mehr gäbe, würde dieses Gerät eine Bezeichnung erhalten, die die gesamte praktische Medizin umfasst. Vielleicht würde man es

## Arzt

nennen (und im Englischen *physician*) oder

## Medic

als Kurzform des lateinischen **Medicus**.

Comment: na ja, es fehlt dann aber im Namen der Hinweis darauf, dass es sich um eine Maschine handelt, weil diese Begriffe sind doch schon für den Menschen vergeben... also zur Unterscheidung, meine ich...

Comment: @äüö "Damit würden aber alle Begriffe, die bisher andere Geräte (und medizinische Berufe) kennzeichnen, **frei werden**." Es gibt durchaus Berufsbezeichnungen, die zu Bezeichnungen der Maschinen wurden, die diese Berufe ersetzt haben. Siehe zum Beispiel die Etymologie von "Bagger": https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagger#Etymologie Und "Medicus" ist keine im Deutschen übliche Bezeichnung, sie kann also für eine Maschine verwendet werden, ohne das damit die Maschine in Konkurrenz zu dem (menschlichen) Arzt träte.